# Show Character Limit From Textarea On Cloned Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[EDIT] Revising original question for better clarity**
This section of this form allows the user to add as many rows as necessary, and works. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to make the character count work on the textarea of the cloned rows.
(Thanks to zer00ne for the all the awesome help here. Great, concise coding! Also provided a jQuery character count in a fraction of lines compared to my former Javascript code.)
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RationalRabbit/2vmqk26b/4/

**CSS**

```
textarea,
output,
button {font-size:inherit;}
output:nth-of-type(n+2) {margin-left:3px;}
.msg {border:none;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {display:table; content: "";}
.clearfix:after {clear:both;}
.RowDeleteButton {float:right; font-family:arial, sansserif; font-size:14px; display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; color:#AC0F0F; font-weight:900; cursor:pointer;}
.RowDeleteButton:hover, .RowDeleteButton:focus {color:#FF0000;}
```

**HTML**

```
    <fieldset>
    <div class="parent-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Name" name="Name[]" size="20" value="" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="HM" name="HM[]" value="X" />
            <textarea class="txt" id="TA" rows="1" cols="30" name="TA[]" maxlength="100"></textarea>
            <input class='msg' name="Output" id="Output" size="3" readonly value="100" />
            <input type="text" name="Location[]" id="Location" size="30" value="" />
            <div class="form-group RowDelete">
                <a class="RowDeleteButton" id="DeleteRow" href="javascript:void(0)"> X </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <a id="AddRow" href="javascript:void(0)"><span style="color:#0F61AC;">Add Row</span></a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // onkeyup invoke charCount
    $('.txt').on('keyup', charCount);

    // onclick...
    $('#DeleteRow').closest('.form-group').hide();
    $('#AddRow').on('click', function (e)
    {
        var len = $('.child-border').length;
        $('.parent-group').clone(true, false).find(':input').each(function (idx, ele)
        {
            ele.name = ele.name + len;
            ele.id = ele.id + len;
            ele.value = '';
        }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end()
            .toggleClass('parent-group child-border').hide()
            .appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    });
    $('#container').on('click', '[id^=DeleteRow]', function(e)
    {
        var jsonData = $(this).closest('.child-border, .parent-group')
        .find(':input:not(button)').get()
        .reduce(function (acc, ele)
        {
            acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
            return acc;
        }, {});
        $(this).closest('.child-border, .parent-group').remove();
        console.log(jsonData);
    });

    function charCount(e)
    {
        // Get the text
        var chars = this.value;
        // Get maxlength as a number
        var charMax = Number(this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
        // Number of chars typed
        var charDone = chars.length;
        // Chars remaining is 100 - chars typed
        var charToGo = charMax - charDone;
        // Display chars remaining
        $(this).next('.msg').val(charToGo);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2<sup>nd</sup> Update

I already said what the issue was in **Update 1**:

```
$('.parent-group').clone(true, false).find(':input')
```

*The second parameter should be **`true`***

This will allow the `clone()` method to keep registered events on the clone. Notice I had said the same thing on the **1st Update**, but I failed to change the code in **Demo 2**.

**Demo 3** is a heavy modification of the most currently updated OP code. It is fully functional and it retains registered events on clones just like **Demo 2**. Added features are: `local/sessionStorage`, sends data to a live test server, and displays server response.

**Demo 4** is OP code and one simple change...want to take a wild guess as to what that might be?.

---

## 1<sup>st</sup> Update

When cloning, use the first parameter to determine whether the clone keeps the registered event handlers the original node has.

```
$('#original').clone(true, true);
```

**See Demo 2**

---

Not sure what you mean by "one row". This demo is streamlined compared to OP code. I added auto height instead of cloning rows.

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo 1

```js
// On keyup...
$('#txt').on('keyup', function() {
  // Get the text
  var chars = this.value;
  // if there are any linebreaks...
  if (chars.match(/\n/g)) {
    /* The value of rows attribute equals
    || the number of line breaks +2
    */
    this.rows = chars.match(/\n/g).length + 2;
  }
  /* Get value of maxlength attribute convert
  || to number
  */
  var charMax = Number(this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
  // Number of chars typed
  var charDone = chars.length;
  // Chars remaining is 100 - chars typed
  var charToGo = charMax - charDone;
  // Display chars remaining
  $('#msg').val(charToGo + ' characters remaining');
});
```

```html
<textarea id='txt' rows="1" cols="30" maxlength="100"></textarea><br>
<output id='msg' for='txt'></output>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Demo 2

```js
// onkeyup invoke charCount
$('.txt').on('keyup', charCount);

// onclick...
$('button').on('click', function() {

  /* clone the first .txt and .msg
  || true: keep registered events
  || false: copy content
  || set .val('') to blank
  || add to fieldset
  */
  $('.txt:first').clone(true, true).val('').appendTo('fieldset');
  $('.msg:first').clone(true, true).val('').appendTo('fieldset');
});


function charCount(e) {
  // Get the text
  var chars = this.value;
  // Get maxlength as a number
  var charMax = Number(this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
  // Number of chars typed
  var charDone = chars.length;
  // Chars remaining is 100 - chars typed
  var charToGo = charMax - charDone;
  // Display chars remaining
  $(this).next('.msg').val(charToGo + ' characters remaining');
}
```

```css
textarea,
output,
button {
  font-size: inherit
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

output:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  margin-left: 3px
}

button {
  margin-left: 90%
}
```

```html
<button type='button'>Add</button>
<fieldset>
  <textarea class='txt' rows="1" cols="30" maxlength="100"></textarea>
  <output class='msg'></output>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Demo 3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    textarea,
    output,
    button {
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    
    output:nth-of-type(n+2) {
      margin-left: 3px;
    }
    
    .msg {
      border: none;
    }
    
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
      display: table;
      content: "";
    }
    
    .clearfix:after {
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .del {
      float: right;
      margin-top: .5px;
      font-family: arial, sansserif;
      font-size: 14px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #AC0F0F;
      font-weight: 900;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .del:hover,
    .del:focus {
      color: #FF0000;
    }
    
    main {
      display: table;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    /* Global counter variable */
    var counter = 0;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main-group">
    <!--This form submits to a live test server, the [target] attribute value
   is that of an iframe's name attribute. By targeting the iframe the
   form can display the test server's response in the iframe
   -->
    <form id='main' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
      <!--The original fieldset is cloned-->
      <fieldset id='set' class="form-group">
        <button id="del" class='ui del' type='button'> X </button>
        <input id='ID' name='ID' class='data' type='hidden'>
        <input id="name" name="name" class='data name' size="25">
        <input id="chx" name="chx" class='data chx' type="checkbox" value="X">
        <br>
        <textarea id="txt" name="txt" class='data txt' rows="1" cols="30" maxlength="100"></textarea>
        <output class='ui msg'></output>
        <br>
        <input id="loc" name="loc" class='data loc' size="30">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <nav class="btn-group">
      <a id="add" href="#/" class='ui'> <b style="color:#0F61AC;">Add Row</b> </a>
      <!--This submit button must use the [form] attribute with the ID of the
     form to be accociated with-->
      <input type='submit' form='main' class='ui'>
    </nav>
    <iframe src='about:blank' name='response' class='ui'></iframe>
  </main>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Click...
    $('#add').on('click', function(e) {

      // Increment counter
      counter++;

      /* clone fieldset#set  true: clone descendants / 
      || TRUE: KEEP EVENTS ON CLONES
      || Gather all of the .data in clone then on each clone...
      */
      var dupe = $('#set').clone(true, true);
      dupe[0].id = 'set' + counter;
      dupe.find('.data').each(function(idx, ele) {
        // Set all .data with name and id, the counter suffix makes them unique
        ele.name = this.name + counter;
        ele.id = this.id + counter;
        // Clear all data in each .data
        ele.value = '';
        // Cool animation and append clone to form#main 
      }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end().hide().appendTo('#main').slideDown('slow');
      // Clear .ui of data
      dupe.find('output').val('');
      dupe.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    });

    // Clicking any button.del... 
    $('.del').on('click', function(e) {
      // Define arrays
      var jsonData = [];
      var JSONKeys = [];
      // This collects all accossiated .data of ,del
      var dataRow = $(this).nextAll('.data').toArray();
      // This map() will create an object literal and add it to an array
      jsonData = dataRow.map(function(data, idx) {
        var D = {};
        D.k = data.id;
        D.v = data.value;
        return D;
      });
      console.log(jsonData);
      // Proceedure to timestamp data
      var stamp = new Date();
      var jKey = stamp.toJSON();
      // Fill an array of keys for future reference
      JSONKeys.push(jKey);
      /* Store JSON data in sessionStorage (can be localStorage also) */
      setData(jKey, jsonData);
      // Save an index of the jsondata
      setData('JSONKeys', jKey);
      // if there's only one fieldset, reset the form if user tries to delete it
      if ($('fieldset').is(':only-child')) {
        $('#main')[0].reset();
      } else {
        // Remove fieldset
        $(this).parent('.form-group').remove();
      }
    });


    // onkeyup invoke charCount
    $('.txt').on('keyup', charCount);

    function charCount(e) {
      // Get the text
      var chars = this.value;
      // Get maxlength as a number
      var charMax = Number(this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
      // Number of chars typed
      var charDone = chars.length;
      // Chars remaining is 100 - chars typed
      var charToGo = charMax - charDone;
      // Display chars remaining
      $(this).next('.msg').val(charToGo);
    }

    function setData(dataKey, dataVal) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(dataKey, JSON.stringify(dataVal));
    }

    function getData(dataKey) {
      return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(dataKey));
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>


  <fieldset>
    <div class="parent-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="Name" name="Name[]" size="20" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="HM" name="HM[]" value="X" />
        <textarea class="txt" id="TA" rows="1" cols="30" name="TA[]" maxlength="100"></textarea>
        <input class='msg' name="Output" id="Output" size="3" readonly value="100" />
        <input type="text" name="Location[]" id="Location" size="30" value="" />
        <div class="form-group RowDelete">
          <a class="RowDeleteButton del" href="javascript:void(0)"> X </a>
        </div>
        <div class="Clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <a id="AddRow" href="javascript:void(0)"><span style="color:#0F61AC;">Add Row</span></a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // onclick...
    $('#DeleteRow').closest('.form-group').hide();
    $('#AddRow').on('click', function(e) {
      var len = $('.child-border').length;
      $('.parent-group').clone(true, true).find(':input').each(function(idx, ele) {
          ele.name = ele.name + len;
          ele.id = ele.id + len;
          ele.value = '';
        }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end()
        .toggleClass('parent-group child-border').hide()
        .appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    });
    $('.del').on('click', function(e) {
      var jsonData = $(this).closest('.child-border, .parent-group')
        .find(':input:not(button)').get()
        .reduce(function(acc, ele) {
          acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
          return acc;
        }, {});
      $(this).closest('.child-border, .parent-group').remove();
      console.log(jsonData);
    });

    function charCount(e) {
      // Get the text
      var chars = this.value;
      // Get maxlength as a number
      var charMax = Number(this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
      // Number of chars typed
      var charDone = chars.length;
      // Chars remaining is 100 - chars typed
      var charToGo = charMax - charDone;
      // Display chars remaining
      $(this).next('.msg').val(charToGo);
    }

    // onkeyup invoke charCount
    $('.txt').on('keyup', charCount);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's great for the character count! Thank you. However, perhaps I did not make it clear enough that the main issue is there is a row of elements, the textarea being only one of those elements. I need to be able to clone the row as many times as the user needs to make additional entries. Thus the jQuery code. So the output could have a class and each would, of course, be specific to the row that it is in. Probably a simple task, but my jQuery skills aren't that good.

Comment: I spoke before I really analyzed the situation, and I am still with my original problem, which is how do I implement the character count for each line. Your code here is lacking some things that are quite important, which were included in my original, working code. Names and Id's need to be unique and both are relied on, of course, when deleting rows and saving the form. My code works. It is the implementation of the character count that is puzzling me. When I get it figured out, I'll edit the question, unless you feel like addressing it. I don't know how to make a code snippet.

Comment: The row this textarea is included in contains text inputs as well as checkboxes and dropdown lists. For anyone else with a similar problem, I'll post a fiddle or something when I get it figured out.

Comment: I don't see any extra form controls. Unique id and name are easy as is extra elements. Before I update to include such, tell me anything else that you need.

Comment: I'll make a better question post. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'll keep an eye out on your update and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Question has been revised

Comment: Thank you so much for all your time and expertise. It is greatly appreciated. However, the sarcasm is unwarranted. My "original" clone was "false, false" as it was blank (.clone()) and that is the default. The "true,false" was at your suggestion, at least in the code. I still have the original copy and paste. And leaving the second option false made sense to me, as it was my misunderstanding, apparently, that setting a deep clone would copy the selections made by the user in the previous row. Once again, thank you so much for your extra effort.

Comment: It was sarcasm targeted at my oversight. I had built 3 demos before I realized that all I needed to do was change one little boolean on OP code. If  I felt anything but good will towards you, I definitely wouldn't even gone past the first demo. I'm glad I could help, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Using zer00ne's Demo 4, this is what I finally came up with. the differences are:
1. Set the first working row as array for database insert using regex. Also designated unique row input id's using parentheses.
2. Set delete button so that it does not appear on first row.
3. My script sets a max number of rows (8).
4. Global variable used to hold row count. Important in the event that the user deletes a row or rows in the middle of the set, then adds rows below.
5. Set checkbox so that the value is kept in cloned rows. "checked" set to false.

The PHP shows how I handled the array server-side so that I come out with arrays in numerical order. This could probably be handled differently, but worked for me. Without using the LastArrayValue variable to handle the last array value, and the ChildCount variable, which says how many rows there actually are, if you delete, for instance, rows 2 & 3 out of eight, you would only have 6 rows, but not be allowed to add additional. Also, without those variables, when rows are deleted in the middle, you will end up with duplicate array keys. This becomes even more critical when you have a max number of rows to deal with.
https://jsfiddle.net/uyz2zjj6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        textarea,
        output,
        button {font-size:inherit;}
        output:nth-of-type(n+2) {margin-left:3px;}
        .msg {border:none;}
        .clearfix:before,
        .clearfix:after {display:table; content: "";}
        .clearfix:after {clear:both;}
        .RowDeleteButton {float:right; font-family:arial, sansserif; font-size:14px; display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; color:#AC0F0F; font-weight:900; cursor:pointer;}
        .RowDeleteButton:hover, .RowDeleteButton:focus {color:#FF0000;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
    <div class="parent-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Name(0)" name="Name[0]" size="20" value="" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="HM(0)" name="HM[0]" value="X" />
            <textarea class="txt" id="TA(0)" rows="1" cols="30" name="TA[0]" maxlength="100"></textarea>
            <input class='msg' name="Output" id="Output(0)" size="3" readonly value="100" />
            <input type="text" name="Location[0]" id="Location(0)" size="30" value="" />
            <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block;">
                <a class="RowDeleteButton del" id="DeleteRow" href="javascript:void(0)"> X </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <a id="AddRow" href="javascript:void(0)"><span style="color:#0F61AC;">Add Row</span></a>
    </div>
</fieldset>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// onclick...
window.LastArrayValue = 0;
$('#DeleteRow').closest('.form-group').hide();
$('#AddRow').on('click', function(e)
{
    var ChildCount = $('.child-group').length;
    if(ChildCount == 7)
    {
        alert("Sorry, 8 is the maximum number of rows");
    }
    else
    {
        var len = window.LastArrayValue;
        window.LastArrayValue = len + 1;
        $('.parent-group').clone(true, true).find(':input').each(function(idx, ele)
        {
            var ename = ele.name;
            var eid    = ele.id
            var ArrayValue = len+1;
            ele.name = ename.replace(/(\[\/?[^\]]*\])/g, "["+ArrayValue+"]");
            ele.id    = eid.replace(/(\(\/?[^\]]*\))/g, "("+ArrayValue+")");
            if(ele.type == "checkbox"){ele.checked = false;}
            else{ele.value = '';}
        }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end()
          .toggleClass('parent-group child-group').hide()
          .appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    }
});
$('.del').on('click', function(e)
{
    var jsonData = $(this).closest('.child-group, .parent-group')
    .find(':input:not(button)').get()
    .reduce(function(acc, ele)
    {
        acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
        return acc;
    }, {});
    $(this).closest('.child-group, .parent-group').remove();
    console.log(jsonData);
});

function charCount(e)
{
    // Get the text
    var chars = this.value;
    // Get maxlength as a number
    var charMax = Number(this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
    // Number of chars typed
    var charDone = chars.length;
    // Chars remaining is 100 - chars typed
    var charToGo = charMax - charDone;
    // Display chars remaining
    $(this).next('.msg').val(charToGo);
}

// onkeyup invoke charCount
$('.txt').on('keyup', charCount)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
// Get the last key number in the array in the event that rows were deleted
// TA is the only required field. If that field is not filled, the row is ignored
end($_POST['TA']);  // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
$key = key($_POST['TA']);  // fetches the key of the element pointed to by the internal pointer
$Ct = $key+1; // account for array start at 0
reset($_POST['TA']); // Reset the array back to the top for processing.
$j=0; // Count only if TA has a value (revaluate $Ct when complete for later use ($Ct = $j))
for($i=0;$i<$Ct;$i++)
{
   if(empty($_POST['TA'][$i])) // Empty may be that field is empty or there is no such row.
   {
    continue;
   }
   $Name[$j]     =  $_POST['Name'][$i];
   $HM[$j]       =  $_POST['HM'][$i];
   $TA[$j]       =  $_POST['TA'][$i];
   $Location[$j] =  $_POST['Location'][$i];
   $j++;
}
$Ct = $j; // $Ct now holds the number of records and those records are in numerical order, 1-8
```